# form.item doesn't seem to get the validated class when entering a value in a jest test

Tags: jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I have a `jest` test to test a custom component containing the `form.item` from `antd`. I've trimmed everything down to clean out-of-the-box code to ensure this is not in my customizations.

My test file contains a defined form like this:

```
const TestForm = () => {
    return (
        <Form id='frm_test' name='frm_test'>
            <Form.Item data-testid="test" label='email' name='email' rules={[{ type: 'email', message: 'test' }]}>
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
};
```

Next I have a test like this:

```
it('Should should validate email input', () => {
    const { getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(<TestForm />);

    screen.debug(getByTestId('test'))
    userEvent.type(getByLabelText('email'), 'T');
    screen.debug(getByTestId('test'));
});
```

When I now run the test, I expect that the generated `form.item` will have the error message bellow the input field if you look at the debug information. This happens when you manually type something in such a situation, so I expect it to happen in the test as well. However this doesn't happen as you can see in the output from the test debug.

What I do see is that the form item is having the class `ant-form-item-is-validating`. I expect this to be `ant-form-item-has-error` (or something like that). It's as if the validation 'hangs' somewhere.

The debug information is:

```
<div
      class="ant-row ant-form-item ant-form-item-is-validating"
      data-testid="test"
    >
      <div
        class="ant-col ant-form-item-label"
      >
        <label
          class=""
          for="frm_test_email"
          title="email"
        >
          email
        </label>
      </div>
      <div
        class="ant-col ant-form-item-control"
      >
        <div
          class="ant-form-item-control-input"
        >
          <div
            class="ant-form-item-control-input-content"
          >
            <input
              class="ant-input ant-input-sm"
              id="frm_test_email"
              type="text"
              value="T"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I saw that the validation was actually also doing a log in the console. With some messing around, I can actually do a test to see if the message appears using spy. Right now I did it with this code :

```
const oSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation();
userEvent.type(getByLabelText('email'), 'T');
expect(oSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Now the above example won't reflect my message, but will work. I adjusted my custom component to contain some console.warn('some message') and then the spy can get it.

Not exactly what I wanted though. Also, I'll end up having console... in my code. I certainly don't want that when I build it. So I'll remove that with uglyfyjs.

Comment: Found a better solution to this? I am in same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Spend 2 days on this but i found an answer.

You can wait for the validation to end by accessing the `validateFields` method as follows:

```js
const form = wrapper.find(Form);
        form.props().form.setFieldsValue({
            email: 'invlid email'
        });
        return form.props().form.validateFields().catch(err => {
            expect(!!err.errorFields).toBe(true);
        })
```